# Sorting a nested list of Objects with specific method

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

Say I have a nested list of objects that have a method called get_name(), which gives you a name for the object, and you have to sort the lists by alphabetical order.

```
my_list = [[obj1, obj2, obj3], [obj4, obj5, obj6], [obj7, obj8]]
```

But I don't know how to make it work with a list of objects, specifically with get_name() as the main method to use, it also has to be assumed that only the list within the list has to be sorted.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

How about simple `for` loop?

```
comparator = lambda obj: obj.get_name()
for sub_list in my_list:
    sub_list.sort(key=comparator)
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be as simple as:

```
for sub in my_list:
    sub.sort(key=MyClass.get_name)
```

This will sort each sublist in-place, using the result of `get_name()` to determine the order.

Comment: That will only work if all the objects are instances of `MyClass` which is not necessarily true.

Comment: @stasdeep: Rather than obliquely complain about my answer, why not call attention to the merits of your own by explaining in an edit why one might choose to use a lambda rather than a direct function call.